# Spacetimes where symmetries vary from place to place?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor, symmetry

Are there spacetimes or metrics where symmetries (like Poincaré, Lorentz, diffeomorphism, translational... invariances) are only local and the symmetries of one local neighbourhood are not, a priori, the same for another, even close to it? I mean spacetimes with "local neighbourhoods" which are not diffeomorphic to each other in some way?

Comment: Far away from a planet, translational symmetry holds to a good approximation. Close to a planet it doesn't. Is this the kind of thing you mean?

Comment: Special conformal transformation is one example

Comment: @ConnorBehan well I meant in a more fundamental level, like, if there is a possible spacetime metric or model where, if it were correct and our universe was based on this, fundamental symmetries like Poincaré, Lorentz, diffemorphism, translational...etc would hold in some areas but not in others (so in other areas of the universe there would be radically different laws of physics)?

Comment: @Rescy_ Is that a case where spacetime would have different fundamental symmetries in different locations (so in some areas we would have our fundamental symmetries like Poincaré, Lorentz, diffemorphism, translational...etc but in other zones these would not hold)?

Comment: If a symmetry *defined as moving from one location to another* holds in one location but not another, then it is just not a symmetry. Although maybe you could have piecewise spacetimes with a flat part and a curved part smoothly glued together.

Comment: @ConnorBehan would in such case (a spacetime with a flat section "glued" to a curved section) all fundamental symmetries (like change from place to place Poincaré, Lorentz, diffemorphism, translational...etc)?

Comment: The suggestions to look at faraway objects which break isometries, nonlinear isometries like special conformal transformations or piecewise spacetimes are all attempts to find some roughly analogous concept which might help for the problem you're trying to study. The whole idea of having something be a symmetry in one place but not in another is not well defined.